# Upper Bound on $\frac{1}{1-\beta u}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u}u^n}{n!(1-\beta(n+1))}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series, exponential-sum

Is there any procedure to find an upper bound of the following expression?

> $$\frac{1}{1-\beta u}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u}u^n}{n!(1-\beta(n+1))}$$
>   Here $u,\beta\in\mathbb{R},\ u>1,\ 0\le\beta<1,\ \beta u<1$ and $\beta$ is assumed to be not of the form $1/k$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

Note that $\beta=0$ implies that the expression is $0$.

**Edit:** Specifically I want to ask the question

> Given any $\epsilon>0$ can there be a $\beta\in (0,1)$ such that I can make $$\left|\frac{1}{1-\beta u}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u}u^n}{n!(1-\beta(n+1))}\right|<\epsilon$$
>   Also, it will be very useful for me if anything can be said about how the choice of $\beta$ depends upon the choice of $\epsilon$. Thanks in advance.

**Further Edit:** I figured out that the answer to my question is negative. Here is my argument below. If anyone finds any flaw please kindly indicate it. that will be a lot of help. Thanks.

$n\ge 0,\ \beta>0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{1-\beta(n+1)}\ge \frac{1}{1-\beta}$. So, 
$$\frac{1}{1-\beta u}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-u}u^n}{n!(1-\beta(n+1))}\le \frac{1}{1-\beta u}-\frac{1}{1-\beta}=\frac{\beta(u-1)}{(1-\beta u)(1-\beta)}$$ So, if I choose $$\frac{\beta(u-1)}{(1-\beta u)(1-\beta)}=\epsilon\Rightarrow \beta^2 u\epsilon- 2u\beta+1=0\Rightarrow \beta=\frac{u\pm\sqrt{u^2-u\epsilon}}{u\epsilon}$$ So, $u\ge\epsilon$ and also, $\beta<\frac{1}{u}\Rightarrow \sqrt{u^2-u\epsilon}<\epsilon-u\Rightarrow \epsilon>u$. So, this inequality is not possible for any $\beta<\frac{1}{u}$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for an upper bound that is some kind of simple function of $\beta$ and $u$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I hope that if the expression is finite, the upper bound can be a function of $\beta$ and $u$. My main aim is to find whether I can make the expression sufficiently small for some choice of $\beta\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks @Lord_Farin for the clarification. In future I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to include the condition $\beta u<1$. Thanks for pointing out @AntonioVargas.